# bash iterate over files in folder, and update the loop when new files in folder

Tags: bash

Hi I have this bash script:

```
for mesh in meshFiles/*.unv;
do
    scaleFolder=`echo $mesh|cut -d'_' -f 1|cut -d'/' -f 2`
    mkdir $scaleFolder

    caseFolder="$scaleFolder/`basename ${mesh%.*}`"

    mkdir $caseFolder

    cp -r baseCase/* $caseFolder
    cp $mesh $caseFolder/mesh.unv
    echo "runing" `basename $mesh`
    cd $caseFolder
    ./Allrun
    cd ../..

done
```

and works fine for all files in the folder, the problem is that the process is slow, so I want to put more files in the **meshFile** folder, and avoid to brake and restart the loop on every new file.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to write a [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) file. With this you won't be able to add files while the process is running, but you will be able to re-run the script after it finishes, and not re-process things that were already processed, i.e. not start from scratch. That is pretty simple to do, and might be enough for some cases.

If you really need to add files while it is running, you need to have a supervisor process that watches the folder contents and spawns processing tasks for new files. This also requires some task management (to know which ones are new/in progress/done). This is not straightforward, so I recommend trying the **make** first.

This is [one intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction), but there are many more if you google a bit. This example is about compiling C code when a .c source code file changes, but the make is generic, and can run any command you tell it to run (like run `./Allrun` if any of the .unv changes, or if a new one appears).